# Sql Server table to XML with multiple child nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
name  | age | misc
------------------
david | 20  | foo
john  | 30  | bar
```

And I want to transform it into the following XML:

```
<doc>
  <field name="name" val="david" />
  <field name="age" val="20" />
  <field name="misc" val="foo" />
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="name" val="john" />
  <field name="age" val="30" />
  <field name="misc" val="bar" />
</doc>
```

I have for this working below for a single column, however if I try to add a second column for another `field` node I get the error:

```
Msg 9303, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
XQuery [query()]: Syntax error near 'name', expected '}'.
```

This is a sample of what I am trying to do and is ready to run in SQL Server Management Studio. I can't find much documentation on the syntax and am quite lost for ideas.

Any assistance is appreciated!

```
declare @MyData table (name varchar(200), age varchar(200), misc varchar(200))

insert into @MyData values('david', '20', 'foo')
insert into @MyData values('john', '30', 'bar')

/*This one works fine*/
SELECT (select * from @MyData as MyData for xml auto, type).query
(
' for $d in /MyData
   return 
   <doc>{
     <field name="name" val="{data($d/@name)}"  />
  }</doc>'
)

/*This one is what I want*/
SELECT (select * from @MyData as MyData for xml auto, type).query
(
' for $d in /MyData
   return 
   <doc>{
     <field name="name" val="{data($d/@name)}"  />
     <field name="age" val="{data($d/@age)}"  />
     <field name="misc" val="{data($d/@misc)}"  />
  }</doc>'
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this..

```
select 
    (select 'name' as 'field/@name', a.name as 'field/@val' for xml path(''), type),
    (select 'age' as 'field/@name', a.age as 'field/@val' for xml path(''), type),
    (select 'misc' as 'field/@name', a.misc as 'field/@val' for xml path(''), type)
from 
    MyData a for xml path('doc')
```

for your XQuery version try this: (I just removed the curly braces) Is that OK?

```
SELECT (select * from @MyData as MyData for xml auto, type).query
(
' for $d in /MyData
   return 
   <doc>
     <field name="name" val="{data($d/@name)}"  />
     <field name="age"  val="{data($d/@age)}"  />
     <field name="misc" val="{data($d/@misc)}"  />
  </doc>'
)
```

Comment: I knew it was a simple syntax thing! I think I prefer the xquery version since I think it's a little more obvious what's happening. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially trying to get XML for the unpivoted data.  So, start by getting a unique row identifier that isn't a field (I'll use a CTE and row_number).  From there, you can use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) and [FOR XML EXPLICIT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
;with data as (
    select name, age, misc,
        row_number() over(order by name) as 'row'
    from @MyData
)
select 1 as tag,
       null as parent,
       row as [doc!1!row!hide],
       null as [field!2!name],
       null as [field!2!val]
from data
UNION
select 2 as tag,
       1 as parent,
       row as [doc!1!row!hide],
       fieldName as [field!2!name],
       val as [field!2!val]
from data d
  UNPIVOT(val for fieldName in (name, age, misc)) up
order by row, tag
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('root')
```

the `ROOT('root')` is to add a simple root element and is in addition to the requested xml format, but I thought it might be useful.

**UPDATE**
After looking a bit closer at query execution plans, you might be better off simply creating formatted text then casting to xml:

```
select cast('<field name="name" val="'+name+'" />'+
            '<field name="age" val="'+age+'" />'+
            '<field name="misc" val="'+misc+'" />'
            as xml)
from @MyData
for xml path('doc')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was considering the second version if I would not get an xquery workaround, as it turns out I just needed to remove the braces! The unpivot looks interesting and may work well for another query I need!